# Get ListView in Fragment class , get NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments

My Fragment layout:

```
<RelativeLayoutLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/my_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayoutLayout>
```

In my Fragment class:

```
ListView myList;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //NullPointerException
        myList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.my_list);
...
}
```

Why I get NullPointerException when trying to get the ListView ?

Comment: Because here view is not set yet. Here is a place when you can create view or inflate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access your Fragment's View before the View has been inflated.

`onCreateView()` is where you create the View, not where you should be accessing the Views (`onViewCreated()` is more appropriate for that).

Your `onCreateView()` should have something like this to inflate your View:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);

    // If you want to do something with the layout here, you can

    return layout;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I couldn't find any fragment layout file which **returns View** to `onCreateView()`. So I think you missed it.

Your code look like,

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.<layout_xml>, container, false); // You missed this line
    myList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_list); // Now access myList from View v
    return v;
```

Comment: I still get NullPointerException.